# En la línea 21 aparece: "A0" indefinido, cómo declaro el pin adc de mi esp8266?

Tags: python, esp8266

El problema aparece al tratar de declarar el pin A0 que es el único del adc del esp8266.

```
from machine import Pin
import machine as mc
import time

segA = Pin(10, Pin.OUT)
segB = Pin(9, Pin.OUT)
segC = Pin(5, Pin.OUT)
segD = Pin(4, Pin.OUT)
segE = Pin(12, Pin.OUT)
segF = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
segG = Pin(14, Pin.OUT)

adc = mc.ADC(mc.Pin(A0)) #Aquí está el problema
COUNT = 0
while 1:
    if COUNT == 0:
        segA.on()
        segB.on()
        segC.on()
        segD.on()
        segE.on()
        segF.on()
        segG.off()

    elif COUNT == 1:

        segA.off()
        segB.on()
        segC.on()
        segD.off()
        segE.off()
        segF.off()
        segG.off()

    elif COUNT == 2:

        segA.on()
        segB.on()
        segC.off()
        segD.on()
        segE.on()
        segF.off()
        segG.on()

    elif COUNT == 3:

        segA.on()
        segB.on()
        segC.on()
        segD.on()
        segE.off()
        segF.off()
        segG.on()

    elif COUNT == 4:

        segA.off()
        segB.on()
        segC.on()
        segD.off()
        segE.off()
        segF.on()
        segG.on()

    elif COUNT == 5:

        segA.on()
        segB.off()
        segC.on()
        segD.on()
        segE.off()
        segF.on()
        segG.on()

    elif COUNT == 6:

        segA.on()
        segB.off()
        segC.on()
        segD.on()
        segE.on()
        segF.on()
        segG.on()

    elif COUNT == 7:

        segA.on()
        segB.on()
        segC.on()
        segD.off()
        segE.off()
        segF.off()
        segG.off()

    elif COUNT == 8:

        segA.on()
        segB.on()
        segC.on()
        segD.on()
        segE.on()
        segF.on()
        segG.on()

    elif COUNT == 9:

        segA.on()
        segB.on()
        segC.on()
        segD.on()
        segE.off()
        segF.on()
        segG.on()

if COUNT < 10:

    COUNT = COUNT + 1
    time.sleep_ms(adc.read())

if COUNT == 10:

    COUNT = 0
    time.sleep_ms(adc.read())
    print("Valor Pot : " + str(adc.read()))
```

Comment: Y cómo podría hacerlo de manera ordenada? soy nuevo viejo

Comment: Oh de acuerdo, gracias bro ;)

Comment: de nada, avísame cualquier cosa :D

Comment: Listo bro, ya acomodé todo el código, al darle a "comprobar", me aparece que no hay errores mas que este: 
adc = mc.ADC(mc.Pin(A0))  //Aquí me dice que "A0" no está definido, cómo podría declararlo, ya busqué en el datasheet y en todos lados me aparece que debe ser así, pero en el programa no me deja

Comment: Listo bro, no me dejaba editarlo, me pedía un monton de texto aparte del código

Comment: creo que debería de ser `"A0"` (entre comillas)

Comment: ya está entre comillas

Comment: supongo que deberías definir el pin A0 de la misma forma que los otros:A0 = Pin(A0, Pin.OUT)

Answer (score 2):

En ESP8266/ESP32 no existe A0 y similares (son de Arduino).

No te puedes guiar por el simbolo impreso en la placa; debes usar directamente número del GPIO asociado, consultando el pinout.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En MicroPython, para leer el pin análogo debes usar `machine.ADC`, pasando como parámetro el número del conversor a usar (0, 1, 2, ...).

Este script muestra como leer el pin análogo:

```
from machine import Pin, ADC
from time import sleep

pot = ADC(0)

while True:
  pot_value = pot.read()
  print(pot_value)
  sleep(0.1)
```